# Notation explanation: $\overset{\$}\leftarrow$

Tags: notation

I am reading [Fully Homomorphic Encryption over the Integers](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/616.pdf) and have come across notation I don't understand, and doesn't appear to be defined:

> The secret key is an odd $\eta$-bit integer: $p \overset{\$}\leftarrow (2\mathbb{Z} + 1) \cap [2^{\eta−1}, 2^\eta)$
>
> ---
>
> *(page 6)*

Specifically, the part I don't understand is the $\overset{\$}\leftarrow$ notation, all I can think is that it's an odd way to write '*choose a random number that satisfies the following criteria*'

Can anyone help, or confirm this is the case please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this notation means that $p$ is sampled randomly. For a similar question, see [Strange notation using dollar sign](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/37787/strange-notation-using-dollar-sign) on Crypto.SE.